# Plotly.js Activate Hovertext

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm using plotly to plot some points, if these points satisfy a condition I'd like the hoverinfo that plotly shows when you hover near the point to display.

desired pseudo code

```
z = {'x': x_val, 'y': y_val , 'type' : 'scatter' , 'mode' : 'markers', 
'hoverinfo': 'text', 'hovermode' : 'closest'}
z['text'] = text

// check condition   
if ( condition)
{
    z['hovermode'] = 'on' //plotly doesn't have 'on' as a setting :(
}
```

Unfortunately the only options for hovermode appear to be: closest, x, y, and false.

Is there any way to activate hoverinfo?  I know I could set mode = 'markers + text' but it isn't as pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`plotly_hover`](https://plot.ly/javascript/hover-events/#capturing-hover-events) event and change the opacity of the hoverinfo which has the class `hoverlayer`. It has the inverse logic of what you are asking for, i.e. it hides undesirable hoverinfo, but it produces the same result.

In the snippet below only dots with an y-value of more than 2 have a hoverinfo.

```js
var data = [
  {
    x: [0, .5, 1, 1.5, 2],
    y: [1, 3, 2, 4, 2],
    mode: 'markers',
    marker: {size:16},
    text: ['Text A', 'Text B', 'Text C', 'Text D', 'Text E'],
    type: 'scatter'
  }
];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv');
myPlot.on('plotly_hover', function(data){
  var infotext = data.points.map(function(d){
    Plotly.d3.selectAll(".hoverlayer").style("opacity", (d.y > 2) ? 1: 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```